# Sorting inside a subquery

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, subquery, realm

I have two Realm objects called `Chat` and `ChatMessage`. There's a one-to-many relationship between the two.

```
class Chat: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var createdAt: Date = Date()
    dynamic var creatorId: String = ""
    let chatMessages = List<ChatMessage>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class ChatMessage: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var chatId: String = ""
    dynamic var createdAt: Date = Date()
    dynamic var read: Bool = false
    dynamic var authorId: String = ""
    dynamic var text: String = ""
    let chat = LinkingObjects(fromType: Chat.self, property: "chatMessages").first

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I need to display a list of chats where chats with most recent messages at the top. Like in all chat apps. To do this, I figured I need to sort the `Chat` objects by the `createdAt` property value of the `ChatMessage` objects linked to each chat.

This is what I have up to now.

```
func getChats() -> Results<Chat> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let chats = realm.objects(Chat.self)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(Chat, $chat, $chat.chatMessages)", argumentArray: nil)
    return chats.filter(predicate)
}
```

I don't know how to sort the `chatMessages` inside the subquery. Or if that's even possible. Searched Realm docs but couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated. Or any suggestions if there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` query is for isolating specific objects, not for actually sorting them. So trying to go about sorting in an `NSPredicate` isn't really feasible.

There's an issue being tracked in the Realm GitHub now for [allowing sorting via to-many child objects](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4554). This would in theory eventually mean you could simply do:

`let chats = realm.objects(Chat.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "chatMessages.createdAt")`

I'd definitely encourage you to add your +1 to that issue so its priority can get bumped up. :)

In the meantime, while not an absolutely amazing solution, you could add an additional `Date` property to `Chat` that is simply `lastUpdated` that copies the date of the very latest `ChatMessage` object. That way you could sort the `Chat` objects directly with that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. Yes, I already came across that Github issue and upvoted it :) Guess I would do the suggested solution. By the way, is there a way in Realm to make the newly added `Date` property in `Chat` automatically update whenever a new `ChatMessage` object is added? Or do I have to set it manually?

Comment: @Isuru My pleasure! Cool! Thanks for that! Hmmm... you could use the Realm notification system to trigger an alert whenever the `chatMessages` property is updated, but that might be somewhat unwieldy. Probably the easiest way would be for you to add a convenience method to `Chat` named something `addMessage()` that takes care of both adding the new message to the `List` as well as updating the `lastUpdated` property. :)

Comment: @TiM late to the party, but just realized this wasn't possible when trying to sort via LinkingObjects/hasMany `Date` property and surprised when it threw on my key path. Is utilizing this type of "cache column" on the parent still the best route? Certainly sounds better than a lot of examples i'm seeing of people faulting and coercing back to arrays which defeats the entire point

Comment: Sorry @RyanRomanchuk, I don't work at Realm anymore, and I haven't been keeping up to date with its latest improvements, so I actually don't know. That issue I linked hasn't been updated since 2017, so my best guess is that the answer is "yes, this is probably still the best way". If you want a more official answer, it might be better to ask on the Realm Cocoa GitHub issues or the Realm support forum. Good luck!